# Should the [planning] and [strategy] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

The wiki for [planning](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning) reads

> Questions relating to developing a strategy while in a game

The wiki for [strategy](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) reads

> Questions relating to strategical play and long term planning in chess

I see no real difference in these tags. Should we merge them? I have created a synonym proposal [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/tags/strategy/synonyms) (currently with one agreement vote and no disagreement votes); if you agree or disagree with the merge, please vote there.

Comment: As a note, you need an answer score of 5 or more on the tag, to vote on the synonym proposal

Comment: @HerbWolfe ah, thank you. Which tag do you need the score on?

Comment: I believe that it's the tag being voted on, in this case planning.